# Setting validation via VBA in excel fails when using variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set the data validation for a range of cells using VBA. I get a run-time error 1004 (so helpful) "Application defined or object defined error" with this code.

```
 With rngRangeToCheck.Cells(lrownum, 1).Validation
    .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=choice
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
End With
```

In Formula1, choice is a variable passed to the function that resembles "=SomeNamedRange" from the workbook the code is in.

The error occurs on the `.Add` section of the code.

If I hard-code Formula1 as `Formula1:="=SomeNamedRange"` it works without a problem.I'd really rather not hard-code it, because I am doing this with a lot of possible values for 'choice' and that would just be less-than-clean code, I think.

I have been burning up Google and about 3 different books for days now trying to sort this out.

Any suggestions? Thanks for helping a newbie out.

Comment: Is SomeNamedRange on the same sheet as the option button?  How is it scoped (workbook, worksheet)?  Are there any other names in the workbook that are identical except scoped differently?

Comment: It is on the same sheet. Scoped for the Workbook. I managed to get this working, though somewhat hacky, by selecting a random cell on the worksheet I wanted to run the code on before running through my code. Seems to work. Though  have no idea how....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your `choice` variable's value is what you think it is? Maybe you should set a breakpoint before the `.Add` line and see what you're passing in. I tested the code in Excel 2003 and 2007, and it works without any issues. Only when I give the Formula1 and invalid range reference do I get the error 1004.

Can you try to run this is a new untouched workbook and see if it works for you (sure did for me):

```
Sub Test()

    'Setup '
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B2").Name = "SomeNamedRange"
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Apples"
    ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value = "Oranges"

    Dim lrownum As Long
    lrownum = 1

    Dim choice
    choice = "=SomeNamedRange"

    Dim rngRangeToCheck As Excel.Range
    Set rngRangeToCheck = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")

    With rngRangeToCheck.Cells(lrownum, 1).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=choice
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

*(This should actually be a comment, not an answer, but I needed to post code so it's easier this way. I'll edit this to be my answer if I come up with one.)*

Comment: When I look at it in Debug, it shows the value as "=SomeNamedRange" clear as day. It is in the correct range, so that's not the baddie either...

 And your code works for me as well. Damned if I can figure out what the problem is. 

The sub is being called as the 'click' event on an option button on the worksheet. Might that make some difference?

Thanks!!

Comment: Sadly, No. Lovely web filter @ work. I appreciate the help, though. As much as I hate to do it, I might just have to go and hardcode it up.. so weird though. I actually have the identical code in another workbook, and it works without a problem. So strange....

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll keep at it!

Comment: OK. Now it gets even weirder. Sometimes it works, no problem. Especially if I run it direct from the IDE, not from a control activation. If I then try a control to activate it, it fails with the error above. Then it won't even work direct from the IDE - even though nothing has changed! I give up!

Comment: Can't help you there, but looks like you're not alone with your problem: http://www.google.com/#q=excel+vba+validation.add+error+1004 - Maybe one of those other discussion forums has the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

This probably should be a comment too, especially since this post is so old...I had the same problem, where it would work some of the time and not others. Using a dynamically named range. The solution that I found was to unlock the sheet temporarily.

```
Private Sub FixDropdownLists()

Sheet1.Unprotect Password:="afei31afa"
Dim cellv As Range

For Each cellv In Sheet1.Range("B18:E18,B32:E32")
    With cellv.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Office_Locations"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "Invalid Input"
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = "Select the location only from the dropdown list."
        .ShowInput = False
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Next cellv
Sheet1.Protect Password:="afei31afa"
End Sub
```

Comment: This also happened to be my problem. It seems 1004 errors can happen for a variety of reasons. It's just Excel saying "I can't do this."

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty old post but for anyone getting here with the the same issue I did, here is how the problem was solved in my case:

I just replaced the

```
With Range(Cell1,Cell2).Validation
```

part by

```
Range(Cell1,Cell2).Select
With Selection.Validation
```

And tadaaa! it works :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost certainly caused by the context of the named range being different from the current context in Excel.

When `Validation.Add` is called, Excel evaluates the formula (which is returning a `Range` object) in the current context of the application, not the workbook or worksheet.  So, if the named range is sheet-based and that sheet is not currently active, it won't work.  If the named range exists in one workbook, but a different workbook is active, then it won't work.  This is why your workaround of selecting a random cell solves the problem, and also the solution of performing a `.Select` followed by `Selection.Validation`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not passing into the Validation.Add a formula that is in row/column. For example "=R2C2:R3C3" caused me problems, as soon as I changed it to "B2:C3" it worked. Also the cells in the range MUST have values in them, or you will get application error.

Answer (score 0):

I have referenced named location using the INDIRECT function and everything run perfect. Users however reported some regular, seemingly random errors and from log file I saw that this Validation.add is causing the problem.
The thing is, that the Excel tool is running in background while different Excel file operated by user may have focus when this operation is executed.

Didn't test the following Code. Hope it helps.

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & sht_sfDocumentation.Name & "!" & gstrRANGE_NamedTableRange & """)"
```