# Setting cell data validation as list from dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set cell data validation from a list which is stored in my worksheet using VBA macro. I don't know how long the list will be so the range needs to be dynamically selected.

At the moment the line .Add Type:= Formula1:="=perfGradeRange" is throwing runtime error '1004' application defined or object defined error.

My code is this:

```
Sub Perf_Grade_Dropdown()

Dim perfGradeData As Worksheet
Dim usedRange As range
Dim rLastCell As range
Dim range As range
Dim perfGradeRange As range

Set perfGradeData = Worksheets("Values")

perfGradeData.Unprotect Password:="pass"

perfGradeData.Activate

Set rLastCell = perfGradeData.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1),    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

Set perfGradeRange = perfGradeData.range(Cells(1, 1), rLastCell)

Set range = perfGradeData.range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(4, 3))

    With range.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=perfGradeRange"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

perfGradeData.Protect Password:="pass", DrawingObjects:=True, contents:=True,          Scenarios:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True, _
AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True,    AllowInsertingColumns:=True
perfGradeData.EnableAutoFilter = True

 End Sub
```

I've seen the following two questions already asked but haven't been able to get any of the suggestions to work:

[Setting validation via VBA in excel fails when using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299478/setting-validation-via-vba-in-excel-fails-when-using-variable)

[How do I avoid run-time error when a worksheet is protected in MS-Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445519/how-do-i-avoid-run-time-error-when-a-worksheet-is-protected-in-ms-excel)

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Range is a class so better not to use it for variable name. Secondly Formula1:= needs parameter as a string so i have used `perfGradeRange.Cells(1)`.

```
Sub Perf_Grade_Dropdown()

        Dim perfGradeData As Worksheet
        Dim usedRange As range
        Dim rLastCell As range
        Dim rng As range
        Dim perfGradeRange As range

        Set perfGradeData = Worksheets("Values")

        perfGradeData.Unprotect Password:="pass"

        perfGradeData.Activate

        Set rLastCell = perfGradeData.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
                                                 xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

        Set perfGradeRange = perfGradeData.range(Cells(1, 1), rLastCell)

        Set rng = perfGradeData.range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(4, 3))

        With rng.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=perfGradeRange.Cells(1)
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With


        perfGradeData.Protect Password:="pass", DrawingObjects:=True, contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True, _
                              AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, AllowInsertingColumns:=True
        perfGradeData.EnableAutoFilter = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: This almost works but it means that my drop down list only contains the value in the first cell, how can I change it to include the values from all cells in the range?

Comment: Do you mean like this: Formula1 :=range("perfGradeRange").Address?  That gives me the 1004 runtime error again

Comment: @db579 Use  Formula1:="=" & perfGradeRange.Address

Comment: That gives me the range as my dropdown values rather than the range contents. So my dropdown has the option $A$1:$A$4

Comment: @db579 Use Formula1:="=" & perfGradeRange.Address. It worked for me.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for the patience and the help!